# How to create automatic tables in spring application?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

"HI
    automatic tables are not creating in spring application and application didnt get any error."

### DB:MYSQL

### "dispatcher-servlet.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Getting Database properties -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />

    <!-- Specifying the Resource location to load JS, CSS, Images etc -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- View Resolver -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- DataSource -->
    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.msebbz.beans.Calendar</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>

        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl}</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Specifying base package of the Components like Controller, Service, DAO -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.msebbz.*" />

    <!-- Transaction -->
    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


    <beans:bean id="Calendar" class="com.msebbz.beans.Calendar"/>
</beans:beans>
```

---

### database.properties

```
#Database related properties
database.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
database.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/#######
database.username = #######
database.password = #######


#Hibernate related properties
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql = true
hibernate.format_sql = true
```

### hibernate.hbm2ddl = update

### "Bean class"

```
package com.msebbz.beans;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="calendar")
public class Calendar {

    @Id
    private String calendarId;
    private String calendarName;
    private String creationDate;
    private String fromDate;
    private String toDate;
    private String status="Active";
    private String calendarYear;
    private String compOffExp;
    private String holidays;
    private String weekOff;
    public String getCalendarId() {
        return calendarId;
    }
    public void setCalendarId(String calendarId) {
        this.calendarId = calendarId;
    }
    public String getCalendarName() {
        return calendarName;
    }
    public void setCalendarName(String calendarName) {
        this.calendarName = calendarName;
    }
    public String getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }
    public void setCreationDate(String creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }
    public String getFromDate() {
        return fromDate;
    }
    public void setFromDate(String fromDate) {
        this.fromDate = fromDate;
    }
    public String getToDate() {
        return toDate;
    }
    public void setToDate(String toDate) {
        this.toDate = toDate;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public String getCalendarYear() {
        return calendarYear;
    }
    public void setCalendarYear(String calendarYear) {
        this.calendarYear = calendarYear;
    }
    public String getCompOffExp() {
        return compOffExp;
    }
    public void setCompOffExp(String compOffExp) {
        this.compOffExp = compOffExp;
    }
    public String getHolidays() {
        return holidays;
    }
    public void setHolidays(String holidays) {
        this.holidays = holidays;
    }
    public String getWeekOff() {
        return weekOff;
    }
    public void setWeekOff(String weekOff) {
        this.weekOff = weekOff;
    }
```

### }

```
"Thanks in advance :)"
```

---

automatic tables are not creating in spring application and application didnt get any error."
automatic tables are not creating in spring application and application didnt get any error."
automatic tables are not creating in spring application and application didnt get any error."
automatic tables are not creating in spring application and application didnt get any error."
automatic tables are not creating in spring application and application didnt get any error."
automatic tables are not creating in spring application and application didnt get any error."